# Альбомная версия страницы

Tags: css

Есть приложение одностраничное, и на портретной версии одна информация, но при повороте девайса необходимо, чтоб отображалась совершенно другая информация.

По идее, проблема должна решаться с помощью медиа запросов, но у меня совершенно другая структура *HTML*.

Как быть в этом случае? Есть способ сделать это с помощью *CSS* или необходимо использовать *JavaScript*?

Comment: Что значит совершенно другая структура HTML? В крайнем случае вы с помощью @media и display: block/none; можете отображать совершенно разные страницы в альбомной и портретной версии

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/gret4dj6/

Comment: ага..Кажется, разобрался.
Спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Если вас не смущает дублирование контента, то можете поместить html для портретной версии в один контейнер, а для альбомной - в другой контейнер, и на css при помощи медиа-запросов из показывать/скрывать.

Comment: Вы имеете в виду что-то вроде:

<div class="first_container">Портретная</div>
<div class="second_container">Альбомная</div>

и уже с помощью медиа-запросов вызывать так?

Comment: @Jumbotron ага, и display block/none